# Unable to show table after POST on same form PHP jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code below that gets the data from the `POST` and return the data as a table. When the code runs I put `Console Log` to see what is happening once the `SUBMIT` button is pressed. When the console log shows as "done" I want to show the table instead, but can't see why it's not happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#searchform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        //alert($('#searchpostcode').val())
        $.post('includes/jobdetailssearch.php', 
        $('#searchform').serialize(), 
        function(data, status){
            $('.table-responsive #displayadd').html(data.Display);
            //$("#table-responsive td").last().append(data);
        console.log("done");
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("fail");
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Why would this be?

Comment: what your console.log(data) says ? it seems 'display' is Javascript property , so it might conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your php script returns a serialized json structure, which can be parsed by javascript.

Try to `console.log(data)` in your callback function to see what is returned from PHP.

Comment: I changed the "done" to `console.log(data)` and when I run the code it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` on the line between these lines `$(function(){
$('#searchform').on('submit', function(e){`

Comment: From changing a log your code broke?? There might be some other things as well then. Try this form: `function($) { /*YOUR CODE HERE*/ } (JQuery);` Do you have jquery at all?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    // Submit Button Pressed
    $(document).on('submit','#searchform', function(e){
        // Prevent Default Click
        e.preventDefault();
        //The first parameter of $.post() is the URL we wish to request
        $.post("includes/jobdetailssearch.php",
        {
            //Then we pass in some data to send along with the request
            searchval:$('#searchform').val()
        },
        //The third parameter is a callback function. The first callback parameter holds the content of the page requested, and the second callback parameter holds the status of the request.
        function(data,status){
         alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

**Note:**

`$('#searchform').on('submit'` work same as `$('#searchform').submit(` but when you use `$(document).on('submit','#searchform'` then it will also work for the DOM added later.

Comment: Thanks yes that shows the whole code through the alert, how now can I add the table back in?